# How to use pytest, hypothesis and line_profiler / kernprof together?

Tags: python, pytest, python-hypothesis, line-profiler

To figure out [Why is this so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69569796/why-is-this-so-slow) I wanted to profile my example generation using line_profiler.

However, I can't get it to work. Here's what I tried:

1. `kernprof -m pytest -n 3 tests/test_conv.py --hypothesis-profile default`
2. `pytest -m line_profiler -n 3 tests/test_conv.py --hypothesis-profile default`
3. `python3 -m line_profiler -m pytest -n 3 tests/test_conv.py --hypothesis-profile default`
4. https://pypi.org/project/pytest-line-profiler/

None of which worked. The first three failed immediately either not knowing `@profile` or pytest or line_profiler IIRC.

How do I get those three to cooperate together?
I had high hopes in Nr. 4, however its documentation states you should might want to annotate your test function:

`@pytest.mark.line_profile.with_args(f, g)`

But my parameters are supplied by hypothesis, so I tried just with

`@pytest.mark.line_profile`

which did nothing.

I also tried the alternative approach of using the command line:

`pytest --line-profile path.to.function_to_be profiled [...]`

However, I couldn't figure out what the `path.to.function_to_be profiled` was in my case. My test function is residing in `tests/test_conv.py` and is named `test_padding`. However, neither

`pytest -n auto --line-profile test_padding tests/test_conv.py --hypothesis-profile default`

nor

`pytest -n auto --line-profile test_conv.test_padding tests/test_conv.py --hypothesis-profile default`

worked. Both error'd saying they couldn't find that function.

I therefore ask: **How?**

Installed is (via pip):

```
pytest
pytest-xdist[psutil]
hypothesis

line_profiler
pytest-line-profiler
```

Comment: Do you have an example that works _without_ Hypothesis?  If so, what's the invocation for that?